# Impossible to change to lich race

Tags: art-of-conquest

I started playing Art of Conquest a few days ago. I noticed that it is possible to switch between human races, dwarves and lichs.

I would like to play with the lich race, but whenever I click to swap it always says that it is locked.

How can I trade for this race?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change race, you must meet the prerequisite rank. For Lich, you will unlock it the same time you unlock the hero Gazul.

Additionally, you will have to pay honor to change race. This will increase as your Castle level increases.

Lastly, you cannot have any buildings or research in progress (and probably units too but I have not tested) when you change race. Essentially, everything must be stopped to make the transition.